# data-list tag php items

Tags: php, autocomplete, datalist

I'm trying to include items in a [datalist-tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp), which is related to autocomplete a form, using php. It works perfectly when I use it in html:

```
<input data-list="one, two, three, four, five" />
```

My objective is to get the former code using php. I want to add to data-list the items in english of $data: *one, two, three, four, five*. What do I have to change in this php code??

```
<?php

$data = '
one:uno
two:dos
three:tres
four:cuatro
five:cinco
';


if($data) {

    $line = explode("\n", $data);
    for($i = 0; $i<count($line); $i++) {

        $item = explode(":", $line[$i]);
        echo '<form><input data-list="' . $item[0] . '"/><form>';

    }
}

?>
```

Thanks in advance XXX

Answer (score 0):

Well,
if I realized you - you want print data by new line..

First, Replace this line:

```
$line = explode("\n", $data);
```

To:

```
$line = explode(PHP_EOL, $data);
```

*(PHP_EOL = PHP End Of Line)*

I think that's your problem..

Work?